# SSD Raid 10 Slow write speeds

Tags: raid, ssd, ibm

We have three IBM servers running windows 2012, all identical, they have a Raid (10) of SSD's. However one of the boxes seems to only be able to write at a third of the speed of the others. The other two I get around 330mb/s however the problem server I only get about 120mb/s. As I said they are all the same hardware and software. Nothing in the event logs, have done a couple of copies and kept an eye on resource monitor but nothing showing up.

Any advice on where to start looking would be great!

Thanks Andre

Comment: Is the firmware identical? Both on the drives and in the BIOS (e.g. properly select AHCI). If any HW RAID card, which model (obviously legacy / AHCI no longeer applies int hat case).

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will try and check this today, i am also looking for a bootable SSD diagnostic tool if you anyone knows one?